# Sorting articles on the front end on-the-fly in Joomla 1.6/1.7

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6, joomla1.7

Is there a way, through the use of querystring parameters or something else, to allow visitors of a Joomla site to sort the articles on the page dynamically? For example, the front page of our site currently sorts by default in date order descending. I would like to allow visitors to select to view them sorted by author name instead, or possibly by popularity. I know that pages can be created with these sort preferences "hard coded" into the menu, but I would rather just allow this on the whole page without creating separate menu items.

Is this doable directly, or through a component or plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 1.5 allows:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=33&Itemid=8
&layout=your_own_layout
&filter_order=a.ordering
&limit=999
&filter_order_Dir=asc
```

Ie. pretty much anything that is in the menu configuration xml for blog category.

Try this, I don't see why this functionality would have been removed.

Comment: To the contrary, it looks like this functionality -- at least according to my informal test -- actually was removed in version 1.6. There has to be a fairly easy way to implement this again, hasn't there?

Comment: Hm, if it has been, then its pretty tedious, you would need to built a system plugin that intercepts all database calls (like Joomfish does) and then rewrite the right database queries to do this. It may be easier to write a new view from scratch that has this functionality added.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late - but if anyone else is looking for a solution:

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_sortable_columns_to_a_table_in_a_component

Comment: This is an answer to an entirely different question. I'm talking about sorting articles on a front-end template, not in the administration area.

Comment: True, though I was thinking if you were writing a component you could still use that in the front end with some finagling.  Another thought - have you looked into the K2 extension?